# How to mount Samba without root access?

Tags: mount, samba

I created a directory /home/user/NAS_mount (permission = 777) to mount a SAMBA share.

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.X.XXX/home -o credentials=/home/user/credential.txt /home/user/NAS_mount
```

Attempts to write to the share have failed: possibly because of mounting as root.  Mount attempts without sudo returns:

mount: only root can use "--options" option

It seems unreasonable that user can not mount a drive to his directory without sudo privilege.  What is the procedure to mount without sudo?

Comment: You might want to see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/does-mount-always-require-root-privileges

Answer (score 1):

Being able to mount something has nothing to do with being able to access it after the mount.

A CIFS mount will always result in a mount owned by root with permissions of 755. Root can write but no one else.

A chmod before the mount is useless since a mount always replaces the mount point permissions with it's own. But you can tell cifs how to mount it:

You could replace root with your own user name: An example using my own user name:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.X.XXX/home -o credentials=/home/morbius/credential.txt,uid=morbius /home/morbius/NAS_mount
```

You can make it so everyone on the client machine can write:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.X.XXX/home -o credentials=/home/user/credential.txt,nounix,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0666 /home/user/NAS_mount
```

Many variations available.